# How do I compile Vuejs components using AWS EB extensions?

Tags: node.js, laravel, amazon-web-services, npm, centos

I am having problems with installing **Nodejs** and further running "**npm run production**" on **AWS Elastic Beanstalk**. I am writing the configs right now and have tried multiple but they all dont allow me to install nodejs.

I tried to install node manually SSHing to the remote machine and running:
"**sudo yum -y install nodejs npm --enablerepo-epel**"

but it installs node v0.10 and then I am unable to run "**npm run prod**" (I guess that is because Laravel Homestead utilizes node v6.11 by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new [elastic beanstalk configuration file](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html) with this:

`container_commands:
    01_install_gcc:
      command: 'yum install -y gcc-c++ make'
    02_download_node:
      command: "curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | bash -E"
    03_install_node:
      command: 'yum install -y nodejs'
    04_install_node_modules:
      command: 'npm install --save-dev cross-env'
    05_run_production:
      command: 'npm run production'`

This works for the `64bit Amazon Linux 2017.03 v2.5.0 running PHP 7.1` Elastic Beanstalk Servers.

Comment: @FarazIrfan, yes they will be run everytime we deploy

Comment: Updated version for PHP 8.1?